# Why isn't my function reloading the UITableView's data?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, twitter

I am creating a tableview that monitors the first 20 tweets from a few accounts and displays them chronologically. It makes the call to the Twitter API and then loops through the tweets and adds them to the tableview. My issue is that when I try to refresh the data in the tableview, nothing happens. I try to call getTwitterInfo() again but it doesn't do anything even when there are new tweets to show. I've tried everything that I could find online but nothing seems to fix it. Any help would be much appreciated— here is the code for my view controller.

```
class TwitterViewController: UIViewController {

    var tableView = UITableView()

    var tweets = [Tweet]()

    let cellID = "cellID"

    var accounts: [String:String] = [
        //this is just a dictionary of the accounts I'm monitoring and their corresponding profile picture
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)

        configureTableView()
        getTwitterInfo()
    }

    func configureTableView(){
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150

        tableView.register(TweetCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellID)

        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true


    }

    func getTwitterInfo(){

        print("getting new info...")


        tweets = [Tweet]()

        var counter = 1

        for (name, pfpLink) in accounts{
            let imageURL = URL(string:pfpLink)!

            var image = UIImage()

            let imageDataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imageURL) { (data,response,error) in
                image = UIImage(data:data!)!
            }

            imageDataTask.resume()


            let url = URL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=\(name)&count=20&tweet_mode=extended")!

            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.allHTTPHeaderFields = ["Authorization": Constants.bearer]

            let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){ (data,response,error) in
                do{
                    let data = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [[String:Any]]

                    let _ = data!.map{
                        let htmlEncodedString = $0["full_text"] as! String

                        let message: String
                        if let newDict = $0["retweeted_status"] as? Dictionary<String,Any>{
                            let newEncodedString = newDict["full_text"] as! String
                            message = Constants.decodeTwitterString(newEncodedString)
                        }else{
                            message = Constants.decodeTwitterString(htmlEncodedString)
                        }

                        let userInfo = $0["user"] as! Dictionary<String,Any>

                        let screenName = userInfo["screen_name"] as! String
                        let username = userInfo["name"] as! String

                        let twitterID = userInfo["id_str"] as! String

                        let dateString = $0["created_at"] as! String

                        let tweet = Tweet(name: username, username: screenName, message: message, twitterID: twitterID, image:image, dateString: dateString)
                        self.tweets.append(tweet)
                    }

                    if (counter == self.accounts.keys.count) {
                            let formatter = DateFormatter()
                            formatter.dateFormat = "EE LLL dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"

                            self.tweets = self.tweets.sorted{
                                formatter.date(from: $0.dateString)! > formatter.date(from: $1.dateString)!
                            }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async{
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }

                    }

                    counter += 1

                }catch let err{
                    print(err)
                }
            }

            dataTask.resume()

        }
    }
}

extension TwitterViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tweets.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! TweetCell
        let tweet = tweets[indexPath.row]

        cell.set(tweet:tweet)
        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        return cell
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I’m assuming that you have verified that there are no exceptions being thrown from the try and no crashes from force unwrap. What I think you should do is move

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

to the outside and after of the if block it is in. I’m suspecting that tableView.reloadData() is not getting called due to the condition check failing in the if block it is in. Try it out and let me know if it helps you out. If it doesn’t, you may send me a link to your project preferably from GitHub.

If you don’t want backwards compatibility with devices running iOS 13 lower, Google *UITableViewDiffableDataSource*. It’s far easier to do it the new way, saves you a ton of headaches specially when project gets a bit more complex by having many tableview state changes to manage. Here’s a good starting point if you want to check it out: [https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/220/][1]

Comment: I just put a print statement inside of that block and it did end up printing— it seems that everything is running but it just isn't working for some reason.

Comment: I just found what seemed to be the issue. I was calling getTwitterInfo() from another view controller, and I guess I had to put it in its own Dispatch.main.async block when I called it. I don't really understand why but hey, it works. Thanks for your help regardless!

Comment: Follow up: I also had to create the instance of the TwitterVIewController programmatically rather than instantiate it through the storyboard. Super weird— I'm not sure how that changes anything, but it only works like that.